# Configuring a Login Helper in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Im creating a helper login to my Rspec tests.

On my spec_helper.rb I have:

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|
   #adding a login method for all tests
   config.include Helpers::Authentication, type: :feature
 end
```

And in my folder -> spec/support/helpers/authentication.rb

```
module Helpers
  module Authentication
    def sign_in_as(user)
       visit 'spud/user_session/new'
       fill_in 'Login', with: ''
       fill_in 'Password', with: ''
       click_on 'Login'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run rspec it gives me this error:

```
spec_helper.rb:46:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Helpers (NameError)
```

The line 46 its exactly the **"config.include Helpers::Authentication, type: :feature"**

What Im missing here?

Comment: Where/how do you load that helper file?

Comment: I dont get the answer Sergio. The spec_helper.rb is inside the spec folder created by Rspec by default

Comment: No-no, I meant the auth helper. Just putting code in some file won't do much. Something has to _load_ that file, to make the new module available.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I guess that everything that was inside the spec folder were loaded. 

How can I add the spec/support/helpers folders to the config?

Comment: Normally, people put something like this somewhere near the top of their spec_helper/rails_helper: `Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require_dependency f }`. This loads everything from spec/support.

Comment: Yes. I already did that. But I got the error: "uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)"

Comment: Too soon then. Rails is not loaded yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was adding the

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   #adding a login method for all tests
   config.include Helpers::Authentication, type: :feature
 end
```

on the spec_helper.rb

I just changed it to the file rails_helper.rb and it works